# Partial Derivative Question, Totally Lost

Tags: partial-derivative

[Question 1(a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCJBw.jpg)Given the following functions: 
$$u(x,y) = yx^2-xy^2\\
v(x,y) = yx^3 + 2xy^5$$

I'm looking to evaluate the partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$ while $v$ is constant.

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_v$$

Comment: They are two different functions. What does $v$ have to do with $u$?

Comment: How's this expression defined?

Comment: I have added the whole question, I have no idea about why choose v to be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $v$ being constant you know how the change in $x$ is related to the change in $y$.  The chain rule you will use is

$$ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Since $v$ is constant, you have
$$yx^3+2xy^5=c$$
So
$$\frac{dy}{dx}x^3+3yx^2+2y^5+10xy^4\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
From this equation solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and put into the chain rule's partial derivative equation for $u$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought $v$ had something to do with the chain rule, now I understand

Comment: @Samuellin The formula ${dy\over dx} = -{v_x\over v_y}$ might be useful here.